# "B1ff filter" reads and returns message

Tags: beginner, c

This is a programming exercise from chapter 8 of a C learning book by K N King. The program should prompt a user for a message, and return it after translating it to B1ff speak. e.g A->4, b->8 etc

The program works as asked in the exercise, however how can I create a more efficient declaration of the `message[]` array? Currently it is initialized to size `N` which is defined as 100 (large enough for most messages), instead of the size of the message from the user.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 100

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    //Initialize
    char message[N] = {' '};
    char ch;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k= 0;


    //Prompt user for message
    printf("Enter a message: ");
    //Get message and put each character into an array
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){
        ch = toupper(ch);
        message[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
  //Print the B1ff speak converting characters
    printf("In B1FF-speak: ");
    for(k = 0; k<i; k++){
        switch(message[k]){
            case 's':
                printf("5");
                break;
            case 'O':
                printf("0");
                break;
            case 'I':
                printf("1");
                break;
            case 'E':
                printf("3");
                break;
            case 'B':
                printf("8");
                break;
            case 'A':
                printf("4");
                break;
            default:
                printf("%c", message[k]);
                break;
        }
    }

    //Print 10 or so exclamation marks and be a citizen
    printf("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What made you think `getchar` gets a char? :) It doesn't do that, `ch = getchar()` actually needs to be `int ch`. These old junk stdio functions aren't exactly intuitive to use and dangerous in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however how can I create a more efficient declaration of the message[] array?

This is an efficient declaration.

Given that the array is "large enough". A statically allocated array is the fastest option. Though it is of course good practice to check that the input never goes out of bounds of the array.

Trying to save a couple of hundred bytes of memory by implementing some sort of dynamic allocation `realloc` scheme isn't sensible. It would slow down the program significantly.

There exists two kinds of computer systems. Systems where dynamic heap allocation makes sense, such as a PC, and systems where it doesn't, such as microcontroller embedded systems.

In case of the former, you have plenty of RAM and you don't need to worry about 100 bytes here or there on the stack. In case of the latter, you could be short on RAM, but neither dynamic memory allocation nor user input from stdin make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Unused: we don't use `j`, and we don't need to include `<stdbool.h>`, `<stdlib.h>` or `<time.h>`.

We have two loops - one that reads input into `message[]` and one that converts and outputs the content of `message[]`.  We can avoid the storage by combining the two loops into one:

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
    ch = toupper(ch);

    switch (ch) {
        /* ... */
    }
```

There's a couple of fixes needed above.  Firstly, we need to check that `ch` is not `EOF`, or we'll loop indefinitely if the input stream is closed before the first newline.  `ch` needs to be an `int` value here, as the distinction between a character and end-of-file is lost when we narrow to `char`.

Secondly, `ch` holds values of a (possibly signed) char, but `toupper()` (like all the `<ctype.h>` functions) works on an `int` representation of `unsigned char` value.  Fixing those gives us:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    ch = toupper((unsigned char)ch);
```

---

Instead of the `switch`, we might consider a table-driven approach.  That would work something like this:

```
char conversions[UCHAR_MAX];
/* identity mapping for most chars */
for (unsigned i = 0;  i < sizeof conversions;  ++i) {
    conversions[i] = (char)i;
}
/* exceptions */
conversions['S'] = '5';
conversions['O'] = '0';
conversions['I'] = '1';
conversions['E'] = '3';
conversions['B'] = '8';
conversions['A'] = '4';


int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    putchar(conversions[toupper(ch)]);
}
```

---

Finally, `puts()` is simpler than `printf()` for simple strings ending in newline, and we don't need to return 0 from `main()`.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char conversions[UCHAR_MAX];
    /* identity mapping for most chars */
    for (unsigned i = 0;  i < sizeof conversions;  ++i) {
        conversions[i] = (char)i;
    }
    /* exceptions */
    conversions['S'] = '5';
    conversions['O'] = '0';
    conversions['I'] = '1';
    conversions['E'] = '3';
    conversions['B'] = '8';
    conversions['A'] = '4';


    printf("Enter a message: ");

    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        putchar(conversions[toupper(ch)]);
    }

    // Finish the sentence
    puts("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

Comment: It says not to add comments like this, however thank you very much! You pointed out many insightful ways I can improve my code. Just curious, is it better practice to use `//` or `/*   */` for commenting sections?

Comment: I don't think there's an objectively-better comment syntax.  It's a personal preference - but be aware that the `//` form was introduced in C99, and older code will use only `/* */`.  I'd advise being consistent if possible (unlike my modified code - oops!)